# PHPunit: is it always bad practice to call expected on mocked query type method?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm unit testing my php code using PhpUnit. Many developers say that is bad practice to put expectation on query method, that is method that only returns something and does not change state of system ( CQS ). Expectations should be used only on command type methods. For Example:

```
$this->validatorMock->expects($this->once())
               ->method('isValid')
               ->with('foo')
               ->willReturn(true)
```

Is considered a bad practice because it couple test to tightly to implementation. Correct way:

```
$this->validatorMock->method('isValid')
     ->willReturn(true);
```

However what if I'm testing class that depends on results of validation of some sort eg.:

```
if ($this->validator->isValid($data) {
         // some logic
} else {
     // some other logic
}
```

Should I put expectation on that method or not? It's a query type method but it is important to test that it was called. I want to know that data was validated.

Of course isValid method itself is tested in seperate testClass ( one that tests validator class )

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of functions that don't modify a state, but just return a value based on input. Validation is one type, conversion is another type.

It makes perfect sense to unit test those functions, because they contain important logic that you don't want to break. I think 'many developers' are wrong here.

Comment: thank You for Your answer but I don't think You have understood my question. I'm not asking whatever isValid should be tested or not , it is tested in seperate testClass. I'm asking whatever when mocking that method should I put expectation on that method or not ?

Comment: Ah, in that case it depends. If you want to test a class that calls the validator to see how it handles different results, then yes, you need to have a mock that returns that result (a stub, actually). In another test maybe you just want to know whether the validator is called at all, in which case you don't need a specific result value.